# Ошибка в подписи робокассы при формирование reseipt

Tags: php, robokassa

Никак немогу понять откуда возникает ошибка в подписи? Пример кода привожу ниже.

```
$shop_id = ''; //Индификатор магазина - данные затер
$shop_pass = ''; //Пароль магазина  - данные затер
$robo_invid = '1'; //Номер счета в магазине
$robo_culture = 'ru'; //Язык робокассы
$robo_encoding =  'utf-8'; //Кодировка
$robo_summ = 6000; //Сумма заказа
$robo_description = 'Заказ №'. $robo_invid .', от '. date('d.m.Y') .', в '. 
date('G:i') .'.'; //Описание заказа
$robo_email = 'garotte@ya.ru'; //Почта получателя
$link_target = '_blank';

//Формируем receipt
$robo_reseipt = Array (
    'sno' => 'osn',
    'items' => Array (
        Array (
            'name' => 'Товар',
            'quantity' => 1,
            'sum' => 5800,
            'payment_method' => 'full_payment',
            'payment_object' => 'payment',
            'tax' => 'vat20'
        ),
        Array (
            'name' => 'Доставка',
            'quantity' => 1,
            'sum' => 200,
            'payment_method' => 'full_payment',
            'payment_object' => 'payment',
            'tax' => 'vat0'
        )
    )
);

$robo_reseipt_url = urlencode(json_encode($robo_reseipt)); //Json, url
$robo_signature_value = 
md5("$shop_id:$robo_summ:$robo_invid:$robo_reseipt_url:$shop_pass"); //MD5

$robo_link = 'https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/Index.aspx?MerchantLogin='. 
$shop_id .'&InvId='. $robo_invid .'&Culture='. $robo_culture .'&Encoding='. 
$robo_encoding .'&Description='. $robo_description .'&OutSum='. $robo_summ 
.'&SignatureValue='. $robo_signature_value .'';

//Ссылка
echo '<a href="'. $robo_link .'" class="basic-hovered-btn" title="Оплатить 
заказ" target="'. $link_target .'">Оплатить заказ</a>';
```

Comment: Могли бы привести пример полного кода с учетом исправлений?

Answer (score 1):

Идём на https://docs.robokassa.ru/#1059
Там есть пример на PHP, в котором формирование подписи выглядит так:
`$crc  = md5("$mrh_login:$out_summ:$inv_id:$mrh_pass1:Shp_item=$shp_item");`

Comment: Ваш пример немного не корректен - мне нужно передать параметр receipt, а не shp.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том, что при формировании конечной ссылки на оплату, передаваемый параметр "Receipt" нужно url-кодировать еще раз. Как-то пропустил эту инфу.